# "Failed to fetch updates - TelegramConflictError" in console when my telegram bot works

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

When my telegram bot works, console is writing every second:

```
Failed to fetch updates - TelegramConflictError: Telegram server says - Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
Sleep for 1.000000 seconds and try again... (tryings = 0, bot id = ID_OF_MY_BOT)
```

I don't know how this is error interferes to my bot, but since this message has started to appeared, my bot works very bad. It works with great interruptions. It can read 1 or 2 command after starting and shut down, or it can not read anything at all.

I don't understand what is this. I has found a question about this on github community, but there no one answer how I can fix this problem. And I found a similar question on stak overflow, but I absolutely don't understand the answer on those question.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that your bot is trying to get updates too often and the Telegram server is reporting a conflict with another request to get updates.  This can happen if your bot is unable to process previous requests.

To solve the problem, try reducing the frequency of update requests in your bot.  Set a longer interval between requests, for example 2-3 seconds.  This can help resolve the conflict and improve the bot's stability.

If you are using a library such as python-telegram-bot, make sure you use the `updater.start_polling()` method correctly, taking into account the best practices for error handling and stopping the bot.

If the problem persists, please clarify the library or framework you are using so that I can provide more precise recommendations.